# Can't create project via angular-cli in windows

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm

While I was trying to install `angular-cli` using the command

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

I get the following error,

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
```

What should I do to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with dependency resolution. Some dependencies that recent versions of Node can handle will cause errors on older versions.

1. Download and install the latest `NodeJS` version ([6.8.1](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)),
2. Run `npm install...` again.
3. Run `npm rebuild`

Comment: This is very helpful. I was about to leave the whole of it and concentrate on the Angular 1.x after several failed attempts.

Comment: `npm rebuild` was not necessary  to accomplish the job.